# Application DB being throttled in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, kubernetes, amazon-rds, amazon-eks

We have a 4 worker node setup and an Oracle RDS in the same VPC and Subnet.
When we are performing load tests on an application inside this env, we are finding that the RDS DB cpu is being utilized to a maximum of only 20-25%.

We even created a service of type: ExternalName to point to the RDS DB, for the k8s and that still had the same cpu utilization output.
Please note that there are memory and cpu requests, but no request limits.

Sample deployment and external service yaml :

```
`
 apiVersion: apps/v1
 kind: Deployment
 metadata:
   name: app-demo-deployment
 spec:
   selector:
     matchLabels:
       app: app-demo
   replicas: 4
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: app-demo
     spec:
       containers:
       - name: app-demo-container
         image: app-demo-image:v1
         ports:
         - containerPort: 80
         - env:
           - name: db_info
             value: db-svc
         resources:
           requests:
             memory: 1Gi
             cpu: "1"
 ---
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Service
 metadata:
   name: db-svc
 spec:
   type: ExternalName
   externalName: db.external-service.com`
```

The same application setup, when performed without k8s, on regular ec2 instances is having a DB cpu utilization of approximately 80%, when tested with the same worker nodes within the same VPC and subnet.

The DB properties and connectionPool minsize and maxsize is kept as-is for both k8s and non k8s env's.

I have tried debugging it, but could not find any reason as to why the DB is being throttled.

Can anyone provide any sort of guidance as to what could possibly be the issue.

Comment: Always look to the thing that *changed* in your configuration: the introduction of k8s, in this case. If the DB is capable of supporting 80% load in one configuration it would support it in the other. If the load is less, it is most likely because the k8s configuration is asking less of the database, regardless of the number of DB sessions. I would look to the memory configuration of your app and k8s, or at any other potential resource bottlenecks on the app side. Oracle would not know the difference between one app configuration and the other, and would not throttle performance like this.

Comment: Hi @pmdba, the k8s config looks the same as the non k8s one, but yes I will look a little deeper to investigate potential resource bottlenecks.